# Can I transform LaserScan messages?

Tags: laserscan, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to transform LaserScan messages from one frame to another? I'd like to keep the message type (i.e., I don't want a PointCloud message, I want to keep LaserScan). I have a *tf* tree setup and I simply want my to work with my LaserScan message in a different frame.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/104026/can-i-transform-laserscan-messages?/) by [kamek](https://answers.ros.org/users/3942/kamek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2013-11-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That´s not easily possible because of the way a scan is represented in the [sensors_msgs/LaserScan](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html) message. The distance measurements are given in a vector and the position of scan endpoints can be computed using the other fields in the message (angle_min etc.). This representation obviously is only valid when using the actual frame_id of the LIDAR.

The easiest way to transform it to another frame is converting it to a pointcloud using the tools provided in [laser_pipeline](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_pipeline).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kamek](https://answers.ros.org/users/3942/kamek/) on 2013-11-22**:
That's what I figured, that you'd have to first convert to a pointcloud. Is there a simple way to convert back to a LaserScan message after the transformation? I thought maybe someone had written a LaserScan->PointCloud->Transform->LaserScan tool.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2013-11-22**:
Look at the contents of the message, the representation only is viable when the frame used is the one where the LIDAR´s spinning mirror is. (Nearly) every attempt to put a transformed scan into a LaserScan message will be an approximation and erroneous (apart from some corner cases).

**Comment by [kamek](https://answers.ros.org/users/3942/kamek/) on 2013-11-22**:
Thanks. I suppose it would work using a different LaserScan message that had ranges and bearings rather than ranges, start angle, and angle increments.